# Condition for a compact, convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to have a nonempty interior?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

For $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ let $int(A):=\{x \in A: B_\epsilon(x)\cap \mathbb{R}^n\subset A$ for some $\epsilon>0\}$, where $B_\epsilon(x)$ is the Euclidean open ball around $x$.

Is there a known sufficient and/or necessary condition for such $A$ that is also compact and convex to have $int(A)\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: containing an open ball?

Comment: If A and B are two compact convex sets with non-empty interiors, then they are homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: It is necessary and sufficient that the span of the vectors in $A$ is $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : This would be true if $A$ contains the origin.  In general I think you really just mean that $A$ has full dimension, that is, its affine hull has dimension $n$.  For example, I would interpret the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\{(1,1)t + (1,2)(1-t): t \in [0,1]\}$ to have vectors that span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Prop 1.3.2 on page 6 in these notes show that a nonempty convex set has nonempty "relative interior." http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-253-convex-analysis-and-optimization-spring-2012/Syllabus/MIT6_253S12_summary.pdf